# Absconding case if not relieved properly

Tags: notice-period

I got relocated without my consent, and while relocating I received transfer benefits and some advance.

After three months of relocation, I got new offer and have resigned.

Now the company is asking me all the benefits for relieving, and I'm not in the condition to repay. While hiring company is denying for taking me without relieving.

I tried to negotiate for the amount which my company has asked but they are not responding. Please suggest what must I do?

Comment: If they don't respond, there's nothing for you to do. Forget about them and move on with your life. Not clear what is your goal here.

Comment: What is your location (if you need relieving perhaps india)? Why would this previous company ask for the benefits back, was it specified in contract?

Comment: Did you sign any contract stipulating any penalties for not working for the company in your new location for a minimum amount of time?  If not, it's on them

Comment: I think the OP also states that the new company won't hire him if he doesn't get a "relieving letter" from his current company.

Comment: No I didn't sign any contract, and after resignation when I received the mail for repayment i discussed with my sales coordinator. And he told me- no company mention this. Until you repay, we can't process your resignation.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have a copy of your contract, request a copy of it (send your request by certified mail, and in your mail ask that the copy is sent to you by certified mail).

Companies can ask for things (and often do) that aren't required. This will likely result in them either sending it to you or not. How you proceed from there depends.

- **No contract sent** -  Any process like this, clarification of contracts is nearly always legally recognized as 'moving forward' with the issue. If they don't respond to your request for your contract, you can pretty much ignore them until they respond; if they try to flip it into a lawsuit of some kind, if you have the certified mail receipt and a copy of the letter you sent with it, then the fault will likely be considered with them for not following through with your reasonable request. If they don't have a legal leg to stand on, you can expect them to never respond as they hope their mistake will just quietly fade away without their practices getting reported on glassdoor or similar.
- **Contract Sent** - If you get your contract, check if it's required before bothering trying to meet their request (especially considering they relocated you without asking you.) Further, since they relocated you without permission, their relocation of you was for a business expense for a service you already supplied (your relocation), their inability to retain you is not your fault unless the contract is very explicit otherwise and your leaving is unrelated to the relocation.

[Note: This answer is for right-to-work & laissaz faire regions]

Comment: Given "hiring company is denying for taking me without relieving" merely getting inaction from the prior employer is not enough. The OP needs that relieving letter.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan That must be some set of laws I'm unfamiliar with then. In the region I live in, employees can quit at any time unless their contract explicitly says otherwise.

Comment: Workplace law and custom vary around the world. Advice that would be good in some jurisdictions would be disastrously wrong in others. That is why a workplace question is often too unclear to answer if it does not indicate location.